# MySQL connection on locahost with mariadb container fails

Tags: docker, mariadb

#### Issue

I cannot connect with MySQL from the host the MariaDB Container is running from. Here are some infos concerning the environment:

#### `docker compose`-file

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      BIND-ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3006
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Connecting with the container via `docker exec -it rancherclientplatform_db_1 /bin/bash` and the connecting with `mysql -uroot -p` unsurprisingly works.

#### GRANTS

Grants are as follows:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              
|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*57237BB49761F29AB9724BA084E811D70C12393D' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                          
|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### On the host

No when I try to connect on the *host*, neither

- `mysql -uroot -p` nor
- `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p` nor
- `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p`

work. The first 2 fail with a socket error, `-h127.0.0.1` fails with
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"`

The port `3306` itself seems to be published to the host properly, as
`nmap -p3306 localhost` delivers

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Any ideas on what to do here?

Comment: BTW we need to make the db available for a springboot java project which I did not mention so far because the problem doesn't seem to be springboot related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB default port is 3306.

so :

> ports:
>         - 3306:3006

you probably want to map port using 3306:3306 if you want to access mariadb on localhost using port 3306

Comment: Small stupid error, big implications... Thanks a lot helping me read my own yml file properly... :-)